# Why this script doesn't recognize the ► symbol and is it possible to solve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf-8, blogger

I use this code to display the Top Commentators in my blog: http://yabtb.blogspot.com/2012/05/top-commenters-gadget-with-avatars.html and we have the option to exclude some names.

The problem I'm facing now and I have been searching for a solution or a at least an answer or clue on how to solve it, is that some name with wierd/special symbols are not recognized by the script to be excluded.

Here is the part where we insert the names and an example of one (the last one), that I can't exclude:

```
var excludeUsers = ["Anonymous","Anónimo","Unknown","joão amarelado","► JUCA ELE ◄"];     // exclude these usernames
```

All names I've placed so far have worked great and unfortunatly, I don't think asking the code creator for help is an option anymore so my last hope is if someone here more savvy at coding can help.

I've tried to convert the name, escape the symbols and have tried some jquery scripts to see if the name is recognized with .text() or html() and it is...

I'm thinking that can be something on the part that read the feed:

```
var authorUri = "";
    if(entry.author[0].uri && entry.author[0].uri.$t != "")
      authorUri = entry.author[0].uri.$t;

    if(excludeMe && authorUri != "" && authorUri == urlMyProfile)
      continue;
    var authorName = entry.author[0].name.$t;
    if(excludeUsers.indexOf(authorName) != -1)
      continue;

    var hash=entry.author[0].name.$t + "-" + authorUri;
    if(topcommenters[hash])
      topcommenters[hash].count++;
    else {
      var commenter = new Object();
      commenter.author = entry.author[0];
      commenter.count = 1;
      topcommenters[hash] = commenter;
    }
```

But my knowledge is not that much to see what can be the issue.

Thank you for any help possible.

Comment: You got the name from somewhere, a database or such. How is it normally presented in code?

Comment: The names are from people who comment and it's me who place them in the script. I just go to the comment, copy the  name and paste it into the script. Has worked always and it does, except with this last name with those symbols. Same user has another account also with weird symbols in its nickname and also the script don't exclude from the gadget. But now I think you're asking where the script gets the name, that is from the blog feed thru json: https://'+window.location.hostname+'/feeds/comments/default...&start-index='+ndxbase+'&alt=json-in-script&callback=showTopCommenters

Comment: There are characters in unicode that aren't visible and there are several possible encodings, among other things. Manually copy and pasting the rendered name is likely missing something. Extracting the name via code would give you the name as the computer sees it so that it will match correctly. Maybe `console.log(entry.author[0].name.$t)` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you tried escaping the characters, but what syntax did you use?

I would say to do it like this:

```
var excludeUsers = ["Anonymous","Anónimo","Unknown","joão amarelado","\u25ba JUCA ELE \u25c4"];
```

Comment: got it to work with \u25BA JUCA ELE \u25C4 Can you update your code so I can mark your answer as acepted? Thank you. I think it's something with the utf charset, I got it to work on jfiddle without any issues or escaping... Only on my blog I had to do it with your code... No idea what is wrong but I'm happy it's working.

Comment: It might be the file format of the file that contains the source code. Maybe it is not UTF-8. You can check with a text file editor like notepad++. Happy you were able to solve it